# Find Max value and assign the value by group by id for non numeric field

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, case, min

[image: this is the table]

I am trying to assign the max value by grouping id field. If the id has L and M the result should be M, if the id field has L, M and H the result should be H. If it has only one value, the same value should return (L for L, M for M and H for H).

This is the code I tried:

```
select x2.id, x2.code, x1.output
from
(
select id, max(code) as output
from
table
group by id
)x1,
select id,code
from
table
)x2
where x1.id = x2.id
order by id
```

The result set is not as expected. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: With the information given, how do you think people can help you???  Please read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please use formatted text for data, not images.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using a window `min()`:

```
select t.*,
    case min(case code 
        when 'H' then 1 
        when 'M' then 2 
        when 'L' then 3 
    end) over(partition by id)
        when 1 then 'H' 
        when 2 then 'M' 
        when 3 then 'L'
    end res
from mytable t
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.  The first CTE defines a hierarchy table.

Data

```
drop table if exists #tTable;
go
create table #tTable(
  id            int not null,
  code          varchar(10) not null);
 
 Insert into #tTable values
(1, 'h'),
(2, 'l'),
(3, 'm'),
(10001, 'l'),
(10001, 'l'),
(10001, 'm'),
(10001, 'l'),
(10002, 'l'),
(10002, 'l'),
(10002, 'h'),
(10002, 'l'),
(10002, 'h'),
(10002, 'm'),
(10002, 'm');
```

Query

```
with
v_cte(h, code) as (
    select *
    from (values (1, 'H'), 
                 (2, 'M'),
                 (3, 'L')) v(h, code)),
max_cte as (
    select t.id, t.code, v.h, min(v.h) over (partition by t.id order by (select null)) min_h
    from #tTable t
         join v_cte v on t.code=v.code)
select mc.id, mc.code, v.code [output]
from max_cte mc
     join v_cte v on mc.min_h=v.h;
```

Output

```
id      code    output
1       h       H
2       l       L
3       m       M
10001   l       M
10001   l       M
10001   m       M
10001   l       M
10002   l       H
10002   l       H
10002   h       H
10002   l       H
10002   h       H
10002   m       H
10002   m       H
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the `code` represents High, Medium, Low?

To answer your question directly, I believe where you're going wrong is you expect `MAX(code)` to return `H`.  But SQL doesn't know anything about the meanings of those codes; it's returning the code with the highest character/lexicographic value, which in ASCII/Unicode would be 'M'.

So you need a lookup table (as suggested by @SteveC) or a lookup expression (as suggested by @GMB) to map the codes to numeric values (in the proper order), and use that numeric value when you call MAX.  I'd personally go with the table, as (in my experience) you'll probably end up with multiple queries that depend on this kind of ordering.  A lookup table is a very common mechanism for encoding priority levels, status, that sort of thing.